# How to pause a for loop in MATLAB to create snapshots?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

So I'm sunning a code which solves an equation over a given period of time. As one would expect, the solution will change as time evolves so I wanted to create some sort of for loop which has the effect of creating "snapshots", which is to say I intend to pause the output at set intervals.

How might I go about implementing such a function?

I was hoping to implement something which pauses the code at defined intervals and then resumes execution on a button press.

Comment: The function you want is called `pause()` and it already exists :P You can either give it a input in seconds, or without input it will wait for a keypress

Comment: What Ander said. But also look at the debugger, you can make it pause a program when a certain condition is met, and it lets you examine variables defined at that point interactively.